# Can I create nested @bot.message_handler() using pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I've recently decided to try creating a bot telegram and choose the pyTelegramBotAPI for this.

Now, i try creating multi-menu message chat with bot using function decorator @telebot.message_handeler() with if/elif/else syntax, but a nested one doesn't show messages from bot.

I have an idea:

1. When users choose "device_problem_forum" using InlineReplyKeyboardMarkup
2. The Bot asks them, "What a device they have problem with?"
3. They choose device through ReplyKeyboardMarkup
4. The Bot asks about "problem an area"
5. They choose an area through ReplyKeyboardMarkup
6. The Bot return list of problems
7. They choose a problem through ReplyKeyboardMarkup

```
        ### Create the FAQ for device problem page 
        if call.data == "device_problem_forum": 
            import device_problem_page 
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Хорошо‍, Давайте решим на каком устройстве проблема?', reply_markup=device_problem_page.device_problem())
            @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
            def (message):
                # Question 1
                if message.text == "":
                    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Какая проблема с ', reply_markup=device_problem_page.computer_problem())
                    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
                    def problems(message):
                        if message.text == "Установка приложений":
                            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Какое приложение установить надо ?', reply_markup=device_problem_page.instalation_problem())
```

So, please, explain me what is i doing wrong? Or i need to use other Telegram API for this ????

I tried to put if/elif statements, try to get a text of message.message_id attribute and than compare it.
Also tried to use call.message.text still no result

Comment: That's not how it works. I suggest looking into examples of the `pyTelegramBotAPI` usage.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych, I did not found which suit me well, can u send page or article about my problem

Comment: You are not going to find an example for your exact problem. But you can adapt ideas and practices from the [official examples](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/tree/master/examples)